# How do I convert from a bugzilla repository to redmine?

Tags: rubygems, migration, redmine, bugzilla

I've tried dropping [bz2redmine](https://github.com/ralli/bz2redmine) into a temp directory and running it as the readme suggests:

```
sudo ruby bz2redmine.rb
```

...but I get an error:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- settings (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from bz2redmine.rb:29:in `<main>'
```

The settings.rb file is in the same directory as the bz2redmine script.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be a bug in the migration script: https://github.com/ralli/bz2redmine/issues/8